# How to enable InstallShield Limited Edition in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition

Tags: installshield-le

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition on Windows Server 2012.
I am working on a VSTO outlook plugin, I need to create installer for the plugin. I found the following documentation to create the deployment installer at microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx

Documentation talks about  enabling the InstallShield Limited Edition. 
I clicked on  File, New, Project.In the New Project dialog box, expanded the Other Project Types node, and then I don't see "Setup and Deployment".

I have already tried devenv.exe /resetsettings. 
devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates is not supported anymore.
I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects

Now I am able to see the following under other project types --> Visual Studio Installer -->
Setup Project
Web Setup Project
Merge Module Project
Setup Wizard
CAB Project

Still I don't see "Setup and Deployment" as per Microsoft documentation.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This is not available for Community Editions of Visual Studio

http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio

> InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio supports the following
>   Visual Studio editions:
>
> - Professional
> - Premium
> - Enterprise
> - Ultimate
>
> ***Visual Studio Community Edition is not supported**.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with VS2015 *Enterprise* Edition.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092703/391605