# How to enable InstallShield Limited Edition 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to deploy my project, to do so I went to the file --> new project --> other project types --> setup and deployment
but there I couldn't find any option like
"setup project" I have downloaded InstallShield Limited Edition. But still same webpage is coming which is asking me to download InstallShield Limited Edition

[image]

and these are the options which I am getting when I click "other project types"

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should download the InstallShield installer from this [site](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio). Just enter information [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF8DB.jpg) then click download now. You will get your serial then install it.

Then re-try enabling in in Visual Studio.

Comment: yes I did it... downloaded the setup.. installed... then re-opened visual studio

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio community? It says that it requires Visual Studio professional.

Comment: I may refer you to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888465/visual-studio-2015-community-isle-setup-and-deployment-doesnt-appear

Comment: i m using visual studio enterprise 2015

Comment: Yes. The link proved helpful... Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You've actually got further than I did.  I only have the "Enable InstallShield" option under "Setup and Deployment"... and all this does it redirect me to the download website.

I've followed the instructions, downloaded the **InstallShield2015LimitedEdition.exe** file, got the email, but I never get the option to actually enter my license key anywhere.

And strangely, even though the download link says it's for VS2010, 2012, 2013 and 2015, in my Start Menu I only have options for VS2010 and 2013.

And restarting VS2015 or my laptop makes no difference.  I never get the option to actually enable InstallShield or enter my serial number anywhere.

[image]

Has *anyone* managed to get this working...?

Btw, I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Update 3, which apparently is supported.  Uh-huh.

Oh, and on Flexera Software's website I found [this page](http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/Support-Inquiry#Activation) suggesting you can "register your product online".  It, errm, redirects you to a page which doesn't exist.  Genial.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me. I had installed both VS2013 and VS2015. Initially enabled it for 2013 and worked. After that I installed VS 2015. Tried to enable InstallShield LE but nothing worked.

It finally worked after simply uninstalling the InstallShieldLE , restaring the PC and Installing it again. For both of my VS2013 and VS2015 installations.

Comment: Agreed, having installed one version of VS if you subsequently add another, uninstalling Install Shield LE, reboot and re-install to activate it in the new version of VS.